# Regex: marking a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to mark a sentence contains "manu" from it's nearest `\n\n` to it's nearest `\n\n`,
this is the text

```
\n\nHolds Certificate No: EMS 96453\nand operates an Environmental Management System which complies with the requirements of ISO for\n\nthe following scope:The Environmental Management System of Dow Corning, for management of environmental\nrisks associated with all global business processes for the marketing, developing,\n   manufacturing, and supply of silicon-based and complementary products and services.\n\n/ tou\n\nFor and on behalf\n\n
```

I wanted to mark just this

```
the following scope:The Environmental Management System of Dow Corning, for management of environmental\nrisks associated with all global business processes for the marketing, developing,\n   manufacturing, and supply of silicon-based and complementary products and services.
```

I tried this regex

```
\\n\\n(.+manu.+?)\\n\\n
```

but it's ignoring the nearest `\n\n` to my pattern and marks much more text than I want

```
Holds Certificate No: EMS 96453\nand operates an Environmental Management System which complies with the requirements of ISO for\n\nthe following scope:The Environmental Management System of Dow Corning, for management of environmental\nrisks associated with all global business processes for the marketing, developing,\n   manufacturing, and supply of silicon-based and complementary products and services.
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You can rule out matching 2 newlines before matching manu `\n\n((?:(?!\n\n).)+manu.+?)\n\n` https://regex101.com/r/qL8nUj/1

Comment: it worked, post it as an answer but replace the `\n`s with `\\n`s please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern starts at the left by matching `\\n\\n` followed by making use of the dot that matches any character. So it will match in this case `manu` without considering any characters in between.

You can use a pattern to match `\\n\\n` and make sure to not match it again before encountering `manu`

Then match until the first occurrence of `\\n\\n` after it, and capture the part that you want in a capture group.

```
\\n\\n((?:(?!\\n\\n).)+manu.+?)\\n\\n
```

**Explanation**

- `\\n\\n` Match literally
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:(?!\\n\\n).)+` Match any char asserting what is at the right is not `\\n\\n`
  - `manu.+?` Match `manu` followed by as least chars as possible
- `)` Close group 1
- `\\n\\n` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qh6lwd/1)

If you also want the match when it is either followed by `\\n\\n` or the end of the string:

```
\\n\\n((?:(?!\\n\\n).)+manu.+?)(?:\n\\n|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5UjqTO/1)